# Make site URL without extension while keeping the server organized?

Tags: drupal, url, rename

I have my personal website using Drupal CMS, for the sake of organization I installed drupal in it's own folder in the public_html folder. But when people access my site, I don't want it to show as: http://nside-elite.techiedesign.net/drupal6/ I want it to look just like: http://nside-elite.techiedesign.net despite the fact that the whole site per-say is inside a sub folder.

I already setup a redirect, so even if you type in the site name without the extension, it takes you to the right place. It's just not very attractive to have the home page looking like its in a sub directory.

So how can I make the site url show as nside-elite.techiedesign.net without having to take drupal out of its sub folder?

Comment: you can refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618326/mod-rewrite-hide-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You could try telling your HTTP server that your 'document root' is at `drupal6/`, relative to the original path you currently have. For more specific information I'd need to know what your HTTP server is.