# htaccess mod rewrite folders hide

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I have been struggling with my htaccess file for a while.. I have the following URL:

http://www.mysite.com/folder1/system/folder2/file.php

I managed to hide the .php extension but now im trying to hide the /system/. 
I have now the following:
([Mod Rewrite Hide Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618326/mod-rewrite-hide-folder))

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$   /system/$1
```

Yet this fails to work.

Thanks.

Edit:

From testing all the solutions with none working I have a strong feeling that my .htaccess is in the wrong directory. Currently the .htaccess is in the folder1 directory.. Not in the root, not in the system, not in the folder2..

Comment: so which URL you want?

Comment: For example: http://www.mysite.com/folder1/folder2/file.php - Without the /system/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder1
RewriteRule ^folder2/(.*).php$ system/folder2/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Do i have to make a rule for every single file this way?

Comment: now check my answer for all files

Comment: @Sinan is it working or not?

Comment: Still not working, i have the .htaccess file in the folder1 directory.

Comment: ohh, thats the problem, now check my updated code it will work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$   $1/system/$2 [QSA,L]
```

Edit:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/system/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ /folder1/system/%1
```

Comment: This rule doest not make the system go down, but also not removes the /system/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/system/$2 [L]
```

Comment: The requested URL /system/system/information/information.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Made en edit, can you try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/system/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Try this.

Comment: This rule changed the url to a completely long url.

Comment: This is very bad solution

Answer (score 0):

Remember you need to place the `.htaccess`-file in the folder1-directory! I think you might have placed it in the root of your site.

Also, be careful not to use a leading /.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) system/$1
```

Comment: My htaccess file is in the folder1 directory, not in the root directory.

Comment: edited my answer. Give it a try