# Apache RewriteRule to hide Folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've read a lot of beginner tutorials and other threads here on the topic `mod_rewrite`, but I can't get my (simple) RewriteRule to work.

My local domain is http://localhost/movies, and my structure is:

```
/movies  
 |-.htaccess
 |-index.php  
 |-/pages  
   |-profile.php  
   |-faq.php  
   |-statistics.php
```

So my URLs would be e.g.: 
http://localhost/movies/pages/profile.php

But I want them this way: 
http://localhost/movies/profile

I achieved this with simple rules in my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule profile pages/profile.php
  RewriteRule faq pages/faq.php
  RewriteRule statistics pages/statistics.php
</IfModule>
```

Now I've tried to sum it up in one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ pages/$1.php
```

So my thought is, that `/(\w+)$` captures any characters and puts it in `$1`
But this doesn't seem to work, so where might be my error?
The output I get: Object not found! 404

Edit:
The answers in the possible duplicate aren't working neither

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$   /pages/$1
```

Or

```
RewriteRule (.*) /subfoldername/$1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mod Rewrite Hide Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618326/mod-rewrite-hide-folder)

Comment: What error are you getting? and What folder is the htaccess in?

Comment: added the location of the .htaccess and the error

Comment: The rule you have should work fine. What address is shown on the 404 page? It should show the rewritten address.